# Erro SQL: Can't reopen table

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com um problema ao realizar um SQL utilizando uma *tabela temporária*.
Eu preciso trazer a `data da ultima alteração` em que a oportunidade foi alterada.

Porém, essa data vem de várias tabelas para a mesma oportunidade. Uma oportunidade é o cabeçalho de um pedido, abaixo dela existem outras tabelas que são ações que a oportunidade sofreu, então fica assim as tabelas:

- oportunidade
- oportunidade_acao
- oportunidade_proposta
- [...]

Busquei os dados de todas as tabelas e trouxe a data da última alteração (alteracao_timestamp) das oportunidades.

Exemplo dos registros:

```
oportunidade_id | alteracao_timestamp | tela
3024            | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | oportunidade
3024            | 2018-02-15 16:18:02 | oportunidade_acao
10930           | 2017-01-05 00:00:00 | oportunidade
10930           | 2018-02-15 16:25:08 | oportunidade_acao
16104           | 2017-05-10 00:00:00 | oportunidade
16104           | 2017-10-03 11:06:00 | oportunidade_acao
16104           | 2017-05-10 00:00:00 | oportunidade_proposta
16104           | 2017-05-26 11:51:00 | oportunidade_compromisso
```

Nesse exemplo é possível verificar que a última alteração de todas as oportunidades é da tabela **oportunidade_acao**.

Agora transferindo isso para o SQL:

```
select 
 a.*
from alteracoes_oportunidades a
inner join ( 
   select oportunidade_id, max(alteracao_timestamp) ultima_alteracao
     from alteracoes_oportunidades
    group by oportunidade_id
) b on b.ultima_alteracao = a.alteracao_timestamp 
   and a.oportunidade_id = b.oportunidade_id
```

Sendo `alteracoes_oportunidades` uma tabela temporária, está gerando o erro:

> Erro SQL (1137): Can't reopen table: 'a'

Constatei na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html) que não é possível usar mais de 1x uma tabela temporária em um SQL. *Caso contrário o SQL acima resolveria meu problema*.

Então tive que reescrever o SQL para:

```
select a.oportunidade_id, a.tela, max(a.alteracao_timestamp) as alteracao_timestamp
from alteracoes_oportunidades a
group by a.oportunidade_id
```

Porém esse me retorna a informação incorreta, está me retornando:

```
oportunidade_id | tela         | alteracao_timestamp
3024            | oportunidade | 2018-02-15 16:18:02
10930           | oportunidade | 2018-02-15 16:25:08
16104           | oportunidade | 2017-10-03 11:06:00
```

O que eu preciso é que me retorne a **maior data de alteração e em qual tela foi a alteração**.
Então o resultado deveria ser:

```
oportunidade_id | tela              | alteracao_timestamp
3024            | oportunidade_acao | 2018-02-15 16:18:02
10930           | oportunidade_acao | 2018-02-15 16:25:08
16104           | oportunidade_acao | 2017-10-03 11:06:00
```

Qual seria a forma correta de realizar o SQL utilizando a tabela temporária?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir do `MySQL 8.0` você pode utilizar a cláusula `WITH` ao invés da tabela temporária:

```
WITH alteracoes_oportunidades AS (
  -- SELECT que reunirá o conteúdo da, até então, tabela temporária
)
SELECT a.*
  FROM alteracoes_oportunidades a
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT a1.oportunidade_id,
          MAX(a1.alteracao_timestamp) AS ultima_alteracao
     FROM alteracoes_oportunidades a1
    GROUP BY a1.oportunidade_id
) b ON b.ultima_alteracao = a.alteracao_timestamp
   AND a.oportunidade_id = b.oportunidade_id;
```

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ztSU1LwVe9we8BbyYL1uq/0).

---

> [**`WITH` Syntax (Common Table Expressions)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)
>
> A common table expression (CTE) is a named temporary result set that exists within the scope of a single statement and that can be referred to later within that statement, possibly multiple times.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma expressão de tabela comum (CTE) é um conjunto de resultados temporários nomeados que existe dentro do escopo de uma única instrução e que pode ser mencionado posteriormente nessa instrução, possivelmente várias vezes.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se conseguiria atender a outras situações que você possui(teria de saber as outras tabelas), mas para esse caso de uma forma bem simples você poderia utilizar:

```
Select a.oportunidade_id, a.tela, a.alteracao_timestamp
from alteracoes_oportunidades a
ORDER by alteracao_timestamp desc LIMIT 1
```

Somente ordenei a tabela para que a MAIOR data ocupasse a primeira linha e posteriormente, limitei o resultado a exibir uma única linha ( a primeira )

[SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e50859/1/0)

Comment: O único problema dessa solução é que ele terá que utilizar o `where`, então ele não consegue fazer uma lista com todas as oportunidades.

Comment: Roberto, porque teria de utilizar o Where? Não entendi

Comment: Nesse caso ele vai trazer todas as oportunidades, vai pegar a ultima ação independente da oportunidade. Não estou dizendo que sua resposta não responde a pergunta, mas tem essa limitação.

Comment: Só perguntei porque fiquei em duvida amigo obrigado pela observação. Não mencionei o where, pois, na pergunta, 'O que eu preciso é que me retorne a maior data e qual tela foi' não existe restrição de condição. Mas voce está correto caso seja necessário verificar uma tela especifica, se faz necessário o uso do Where

Comment: Realmente esqueci de colocar na pergunta que são várias oportunidades, alterei a pergunta acrescentando esse detalhe. O seu SQL está correto, mas precisaria fazer uma alteração para atender todas as oportunidades.

Comment: Voce pode adicionar um exemplo com varias oportunidades?

Comment: Adicionado conforme solicitado.

Comment: Não entendi então amigo desculpe, o resultado da query que postei vai sempre trazer 1 linha e esta linha contendo a tela e a data da modificação, sendo essa a data de modificção mais recente. Essa query continua funcionando para o exemplo que voce apresentou. Montei um sqlFiddle para voce olhar, editei a resposta

Comment: É que seu SQL me retorna apenas 1 registro. Na pergunta eu coloquei o resultado esperado ( na parte: *Então o resultado deveria ser* ). Para exemplificar: Pegue o link que você postou, e altere o SQL para o meu da pergunta que está na parte `Agora transferindo isso para o SQL`, veja o resultado, e irá retornar o que eu preciso. Porém, `alteracoes_oportunidades` é uma tabela temporária e com isso não consigo realizar o meu SQL porque gera erro (`Can't reopen table`), esse erro está [doc. do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html) que preciso contornar